# Rails -- Password Recovery

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, password-recovery

This question may be a little abstract, but I was wondering what the best/standard method for implementing password recovery is.  I am trying to implement it in my code right now but the method I'm starting to use seems a little roundabout / confusing and I wanted to know what the "Rails way" to do this is.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Devise has most patterns implemented, give it a look https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Answer (score 6):

Passwords should generally be hashed (ideally with a salt) rather than encrypted, so that they can not be decrypted. Then, later, to check if a user entered their password correctly, you take whatever they entered and use the same salt and hash function, and see if it matches the hash you have in the database.

Stored in this way, passwords cannot be recovered. The standard way to go about recovering a lost password is:

1. Bob enters his email address (or username or whatever) to indicate who he is
2. A "password reset token" is generated, generally a long string of letters and numbers, and stored in the database associated to Bob in some way.
3. Bob is sent an email with the password reset token attached in some way, usually in a URL (for example, `http://fakesite.com/reset_password?token=long_token_generated_in_step_2`.
4. When Bob visits that URL, the site verifies that the reset token is valid, and allows Bob to choose a *new* password, which is then salted/hashed in the same way as the password he lost.

Devise, an authentication gem for Rails, has a [Recoverable strategy](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb) that follows this pattern.

Some sites apply additional security checks, since email is not 100% secure. For example, you may require that, to get a password reset email, the user must answer a secret question (usually set up when the create their account).